# Неправильное округление чисел с плавающей точкой в PHP 7

Tags: php7

Есть 2 сервера:

Первый: Centos 6, PHP 5.3.3

Второй: Centos 7, PHP 7.1.14

Выполнение одного и того же кода дает разный результат.

Код:

```
$arResult = array();

$arResult['result'] = round(4 / 100, 2);

echo json_encode($arResult);
```

Результат выполнения:

- на первом сервере: {"result":0.04}
- на втором: {"result":0.040000000000000001}

Подскажите, что с этим делать ? Т.е. добиться результата на втором сервере идентичного первому.

P.S. переменная должна остаться числом, не стрингом.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в округление, оно корректно, вместо
var_export($iVal); выполните var_dump($iVal);

Почитайте :

> http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php

Для теста можете выполнить

```html
$iVal = 0.04;

 var_export($iVal);
```

Это стандартное поведение числа с плавающей точкой. При использование var_export и подобных функций, к ним применяются определенные условия. 
Вас конкретно интересует свойство serialize_precision в Вашем phpini файле. Его изменение, изменит текущее поведение.

Данное поведение корректно и встречается во многих языках, изучите ссылки что я дал выше.

можно так

```html
$iVal = 0.04;
ini_set('serialize_precision', 1);
 var_export($iVal);
```

На примере вашего кода

```html
$arResult = array();
ini_set('serialize_precision', 1);

$arResult['result'] = round(4 / 100, 2);
echo json_encode($arResult);
ini_set('serialize_precision', 17);
```

главное не забудьте вернуть стандартный параметр.

Comment: Изменил формулировку вопроса. Округление не корректно.

Comment: Округление корректно. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Хм.. Действительно изменение serialize_precision дает нужный результат. Алексей, подскажите, чем изменение serialize_precision на продакшн сервере чревато ? Кроме адекватного результата округления в php =)

Comment: Везде где от него будет ожидаться стандартное поведение, его не будет, следовательно не работать может все что ожидает его. 
Можно поменять не так болезненно в нужных фрагментах кода, примеры выше я привел. 
Лучше всего  переписать ваш код так что бы подобных вопросов не возникало.

Comment: Разве приведенный выше код можно иначе переписать, чтобы не изменять serialize_precision ?

Comment: Вы можете работать как со строкой, и решать проблему приведения уже на клиенте. 
Можете менять поведение в конкретном случае, через ini_set.
Можете передавать данные в таком формате, а уже на клиенте отбрасывать не нужное, приводя к желаемому виду. 

http://floating-point-gui.de/ - Вот сайт посвященный проблеме математических операций с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей. Хорошего дня.

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, примите его как верный, хорошего дня.